# bootstrap 4 popover title is misaligned

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

Hey I'm having the following issue with bootstrap 4 (using Laravel) with popovers:

[image]

As you can see, the title (h3) is somehow to the left of the text, but when it fades out it seems to align correctly. I've tried many things to solve this, but I couldn't get anything to fix it.

---

My `<a>` looks as follows, using font awesome:

```
        <a tabindex="{{ $concept->id }}" class="fa fa-info-circle no-link" id="popover-concept-{{$concept->id}}" aria-hidden="true" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus" title="Last edited on" data-content="{{ $concept->updated_at }}"></a>
```

My jquery for popovers looks as follows:

```
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            delay: {"show" : 250, "hide" : 250},
            placement: "top",
            trigger: "hover",
            offset: "0 48px", // tether
            //template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="popover-arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
            container: 'body',
        });
```

I've tried removing the body container, changing offsets.. and more.. Having it toggle on click (or any other way for that matter) doesn't solve it either. When I change the template to not include the h3 title, it'll work correctly.. but I really want the title..

Comment: Inspect it with the web inspector. Must be a custom, conflicting class

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've tried that, but I can't find any conflicts whatsoever. :(

Comment: can you create an example for us to replicate? A reduced test case? On Codepen or such?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without seeing it but make sure your h3.popover-title doesn't have a float on it and is displaying block. Issues could've been inherited from elsewhere

```
float: none;
display: block;
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the popover-title class, but it didn't make any difference. There is nothing else styling the popover.